# Mount ISO File with Native Windows Application When Having Different File Association

Tags: windows, mount, iso-image, winzip

I have an .iso file association with WinZip and there's no default option for mounting the image instead of opening it in WinZip. Any suggestions? Again, I'd like to use the default native application only

Comment: Your question title begins "Mount ISO File ..." and your question ends "Any suggestions?" This is pretty vague and open-ended; even misleading. When you get two answers that you think are missing the point of your question, you should [edit] the question to clarify what you want. As it stands, you're wasting the time of people who want to help you and don't want to wade through all your comments.

Comment: You are right, let me update the question to emphasize the real issue

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a piece of software such as PowerISO or MagicISO, they are designed for this sort of thing.

WinZip is an archive/unarchive utility such as the likes of 7-Zip and WinRar. They can open iso's as they are a form of archive.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I prefer to use the one that comes with the system

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili I wasn't aware of a windows-native mounting utility? To my knowledge, WinZip is an application developed by WinZip International LLC.

I know you said you'd prefer to use something that comes with the system, but here is a list of free-ware and safe mounting utilities. [List of freeware ISO Mounting utilities](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/10-free-software-to-mount-cd-or-dvd-iso-image-file-as-virtual-drives/)

Comment: @Michael: Windows 8 natively supports ISO mounting.

Comment: @Giorgio: I don't have Winzip installed so I can't really answer the question. I think you may have to break the iso association with WinZip, but how to do that I don't know. Another options would be to right-click the iso and select the 'Mount' option.

Comment: @Berend I hadn't made the connection as the question wasn't descriptive enough.

Comment: @Berend If you are using Windows 8 then add that tag to your question ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I know _I_ am using Windows 8, but I can't really speak for the OP, can I?

Comment: @Berend. Sorry got confused about who was who :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for Start >> Control Panel >> All Control Panel Items >> Default Programs >> Associate a file type or protocol with a program ?

On Windows 7, that hop through menus will get you to the point that you can remove the association (break the association) and reassign the association for .iso to whatever software is your preference (like the extract tool that comes with Windows).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: On Windows 10, this answer is right on the money, actually. Go to Default Programs > Choose default apps by file type, then scroll down to the ".iso" entry, where you should see WinZip assigned. Click on WinZip, and from the popup menu, select Windows Explorer. This should enable built-in features to mount and mount ISO images.

Answer (score 0):

The virtualclone drive by Elaborate Bytes is my favorite free mounting utility.

P.S: I am not affiliated with any software I mention here

Comment: Cmon guys, my main interest is not to mount the thing, but rather, understand how to set up the system, as for now I cannot find an appropriate option for performing the operation... Thanks

Comment: FAKOOR: Do you by any chance have a financial relationship with this company? If so, you must disclose it. And, in any case, please see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511)

Comment: Thanks for the guideline. No, no relationships with the vendors. Sorry for lack of info.

Comment: @Giorgi So you want something like "Open with...."? Or you simply want the context menu "Burn with image writer..." back. Am I right?